# how to use insert and select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, phpmyadmin

we are facing a big problem How can we insert  value from 1 column to other column  of same table

```
  SELECT *
From (
SELECT  answers.latitude as first_lat,answers.longitude as first_long ,answers.id as first_column  from answers  WHERE answers.question_id=142 and answers.survey_id=194
) as c1,
(
SELECT  answers.latitude as second_lat,answers.longitude as second_long ,answers.id   as second_column from answers  WHERE answers.question_id=146 and answers.survey_id=194
    ) as c2
    where first_column+1=second_column
```

My above query have following Result But now **we are facing problem how  can we insert Value from 
    Second_lat to first lat ,long**

[image]
**May it helpfull** 
Actual table structure 
These are two convective rows in database  146 & 142 
    Question_id 146  have lat ,long And we want to move lat ,long from 146 to 142

```
  id       question_id ,lat,long
   1     146 ,22.2222.11.1111
   2    142,0,0 
   3     146 ,22.2222.11.1111
   4    142,0,0
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you convert from rows to columns you can achieve this in rows as well ?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE is the way to do it
Something like as below. You might need to run two queries one for longitude and one for latitude.
UPDATE answers t1 SET t1.longitude = (SELECT t2.longitude FROM answers t2 WHERE t1.rownum + 1 = t2.rownum)

Depending on the database you are using, that rownum might differ

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
update answers as a1, answers as a2
  set a1.latitude=a2.latitude,
  a1.longitude=a2.longitude
where a1.id+1=a2.id
  and a1.question_id=142
  and a2.question_id=146
  and a1.survey_id=194
  and a2.survey_id=194
```